# Calculating total from a html table using Angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am really new with Angular and just finished the tutorial and my contact-list app. I would like to perform some simple calculations with rails generated html table using AngularJS on the client-side.

My table looks like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Group</th>
        <th>Current</th>
        <th>Previous</th>
        <th>Difference %</th> 
    </tr>   
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>10</td> 
        <td>20</td> 
        <td>100%</td> //Want to use Angular
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Total:</td> 
        <td>10</td> //Want to use Angular
        <td>20</td> //Want to use Angular
    </tr>
</table>
```

I could write it with simple Javascript, however with time I would like these numbers to change styles, depending on the result, draw graphs, etc. 
Please point me into the right direction! Thank you!

Comment: angular works with model not html so first instead try to create a model and use ng-repeat to lay out the table

Comment: so its probably more effective to use plain JS in this case I guess

Comment: Right, you structure you model data. and do aggregation in the model.